# Prove that the linear map multiplication by x^2 is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> multiplication by $x^2$, defined by $T \in \mathbb{L(P(R),P(R))}$ by $$(Tp)(x) = x^2p(x)$$

My textbook claims that this linear transformation is not surjective because 1 is not in the range. However, why wouldn't 1 be in range$(T)$?

I am also not sure what the vector space $P(R)$ or $p(x)$ is supposed to be either. I can't seem to find a clear definition in the book.

Any clarification would be helpful, thanks

Comment: It is likely that $\Bbb {P(R)}$ denotes the set of polynomials with real coefficients

Comment: $\Bbb P(\Bbb R)$ stands for the set of polynomials with real coefficients, and $x^2$ is treated as a polynomial.

Comment: OH okay, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

As Omn and Berci say, I too think that $\mathbb{P}(n)$ is the linear space of polynomials with real coefficients.

Under this assumption, $T$ is the left multiplication by $x^2$ map.

In the range of $T$ you only have polynomials of degree $\geq 2$ and the zero polynomial $p(x)\equiv 0$. You are missing all polynomials of degree $0$ and $1$.

To be precise, the exact range is all polynomials whose coefficient of degree $0$ and $1$ are zero.